# Implementing a golang like channels structure in python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I was trying to implement a golang like `channel`in python. I used asyncio package and some simple generators to implement this.

```
import asyncio


def channel(capacity):
    # A very lazy channel implementation
    size = 0
    data = []
    while size < capacity:
        item = yield
        data.append(item)
        size += 1
    for item in data:
        yield item


async def worker(id:int, jobs:channel, results:channel):
    print(f"worker : {id} started")
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    for job in jobs:
        print(f"worker : {id} received job {job}")
        result = job * job
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        results.send(result)


async def main():
    jobs = channel(10)
    results = channel(10)
    # priming jobs and results channel
    next(jobs)
    next(results)
    for i in range(10):
        jobs.send(i)
    await worker(1, jobs, results)
    await worker(2, jobs, results)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

even though the code seems to run, the second worker is not spawning until the first worker consumes all the jobs.

I added `asyncio.sleep(0)` for forcing the context switch, but still the first worker is not returning the control back to the main co-routine.

What am I doing wrong here? Does it have anyhing to do with the `channel generator`?

Result :

```
worker : 1 started
worker : 1 received job 1
worker : 1 received job 2
worker : 1 received job 3
worker : 1 received job 4
worker : 1 received job 5
worker : 1 received job 6
worker : 1 received job 7
worker : 1 received job 8
worker : 1 received job 9
worker : 2 started
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do:

```
    await worker(1, jobs, results)
```

You are waiting for this coroutine to end, and when it ends the next one is executed (once the channel is empty). So the first worker consumes all the items.

To solve this you have to run the two coroutines together.

With [gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently), transform all coroutines into tasks and wait for all of them to finish:

```
    # with gather
    await asyncio.gather(
        worker(1, jobs, results),
        worker(2, jobs, results)
    )
```

With [tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks) (from doc):

> Wrap the coro coroutine into a Task and schedule its execution. Return the Task object.

And then await the tasks.

```
    task_1 = asyncio.create_task(worker(1, jobs, results))
    task_2 = asyncio.create_task(worker(2, jobs, results))

    await task_1
    await task_2
```

Also don't create your channel, use [asyncio.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) with a `maxsize` as a channel.

Comment: Thank you. I tried using `gather` and could see that the second worker also started consuming jobs. I'm pretty new to asyncio and had a hard time figuring this out.